# Laptop won't boot more than a half second when the HDD drive cable is connected

Tags: hard-drive, boot, laptop, dell-latitude

I have a Dell Latitude e5570 and when I got it, all it was missing was a HDD drive cable (the cable in the bottom that connects the hard drive to the motherboard)

The image shows the HDD cable unplugged from the system sitting beside it. I just added it for reference.

[image: Screenshot.]

Well I finally got my hands on that cable but when it's plugged in, the computer won't boot whatsoever. The power light turns on for a brief moment on the power button and then proceeds to shut off. No fans start, no response on the screen, just on and off really quickly.

And yesterday when I was trying to install Windows to external drive to run it, the computer fires up fine when the HDD drive cable isn't plugged in. But the moment that cable is plugged in the computer just won't fire up even a little bit I even had it unplugged and then after the computer started to boot I plugged in the HDD drive cable and it shut the computer off.

The situation doesn't change when a HDD is plugged into the cable, it's just when I plug it in on the bottom. The laptop stops even trying to work.

I'm really really scratching my head here and could use some help cause I've been computerless for a while and basically my life revolves around it.

Comment: @giacomo1968  I appreciate the edit and all, but I have some questions and comments about it.. 1: why get rid of the friendly hello at the start? Greetings are important and it helps portray my frustration in the situation. 2: it's not a HDD DRIVE cable, it is a DRIVER cable as Dell has it labeled. 3: I may not be 100% sure what the extra "D" is for in HDD (probably disk or drive) but switching my HDDs to HDs was unnecessary LOL. Nonetheless I thank you one way or another

Comment: You’re welcome! That said: “…it helps portray my frustration in the situation.” This site is about solving problems; not emotional venting. Just state the facts, provide details and allow the question to stand on it’s own. This is clearly explained in [the help center section on behavior](https://superuser.com/help/behavior): “Thanks and other statements of appreciation are unnecessary, and, like other chitchat, should not be included. If you use signatures, taglines, greetings, thanks, or other chitchat, they will be removed to reduce noise in the questions and answers.”

Comment: Please know that @Giacomo1968 is correct.  He didn't get 48k+ points here for nothing.  This is not a "forum", it is a Q&A site.  The less greetings or frustrations the better.  I love that you are using the service but we have methods here for a reason. :)  Good luck finding your answer!!

Comment: How are you sure that your new cable is good?

Comment: To echo what @SeñorCMasMas states, this all sounds like an issue with the cable. If the computer is shutting down immediately, it seems to be that either the cable is causing a short or the drive itself is defective in a way that causes a short. What happens if just the cable — without a drive connected to it — is plugged in? If the computer shuts down, the cable is bad. If it only shuts down if the cable is connected to a hard drive, then the issue _might_ be the drive causing a short.

Comment: I understand and also agree, thinking it over, its just a useless sentence considering that isnt the issue at hand :)  And honestly, no, im not sure how to tell whether the cable is faulty or not. I just took it out of the package and would like to assume its in working order. However, I dont know a way i could test that aside from having a duplicate computer to test it on

Comment: ugh, a faulty cable is the last thing id hoped the issue was.. i suppose ill order anoter from a different site and see how it goes.. thanks

Comment: @xMajix Make sure you buy the correct cable for this model. 4G9GN is the part number for the cable.